# Drive mounts with mount, but not autofs automount

Tags: debian, automounting, autofs

Second day on this, so I'm definitely doing something wrong.

Can mount a spare drive to user's home subdirectory mount point, with correct permissions for user to use it.
Doing that with just simple mount [device] [mountpoint]
Device is ext4 logical volume, which fscks clean.

If I tell automount/autofs do it, it's not usable at all.
The subdirectory is created, but owned and only accessible by root.
The automount itself fails with:

> ...wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdi, missing codepage or helper program, or other error. mount(ext2): failed to
>   mount /dev/xvdi (type ext4) on....

The current automap options I'm using are:

`-fstype=auto,defaults,noatime,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770  :/dev/xvdi`

I've tried many - fstype=ext4, ext2, with an without ids and modes, and without any options.

I'm also using udev rules, because this drive is not always connected:

```
KERNEL="xvdi", OWNER="user", GROUP="user", MODE="0770"
```

Does anyone have something similar working?
Is there something easier than autofs, which is not systemd based?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--fstype=autofs` instead of filesystem format. Please check the following example for your information:

```
-fstype=auto,defaults,noatime,gid=100,uid=1000,nls=utf8 :/dev/sdax
```

Comment: Thanks. Same error so far.

Comment: @bigsy Did you check through the format filesystem ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by format filesystem. The drive mounts with mount command, and fsck says it's clean. Only automount can't figure it out.

Comment: @bigsy Could you please provide df -h output ?

Comment: @bigsy, Please mention the driver name like xvdi1 into autofs file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have several things wrong here. Let's look at the parts of the error message one by one:

> ...wrong fs type...

> mount(ext2): failed to mount /dev/xvdi (type ext4) on....

First, the error message reveals that the automounter is trying to mount an `ext4` filesystem as `ext2` one, which might not be a good thing.

When mounting manually or using `/etc/fstab`, you can specify the filesystem type as `auto`, which will cause the kernel to attempt all filesystem types listed in `/proc/filesystems` that are not marked `nodev`, until it finds one that succeeds or it runs out of filesystem types to try. It is possible that the automounter does not like doing multiple attempts like that, and interprets the failure of the first mount attempt (as type `ext2` here) as a complete failure to mount.

So, please just specify the filesystem accurately as `fstype=ext4` when automounting.

> ... bad option, ...

Options like `uid=`, `gid=`, `file_mode=` and `dir_mode=` only exist for *some* filesystem types, not all. The filesystem types that have options like those either don't natively support unix-style file permissions, or have some special purpose. More specifically, the `file_mode` and `dir_mode` seem to only exist for mounting SMB/CIFS network filesystems; other filesystem types use slightly different option names - assuming they even have the corresponding options in the first place.

You should remove these options. Instead, as a system administrator, you should initially just `chown`/`chmod`/`chgrp` the root directory of the mounted filesystem to something that allows the user(s) to use it as desired, and let the user(s) create their own sub-directories.

If necessary, you can use a setgid bit on a directory to direct a particular group to be used for all files and sub-directories created in that directory, or a default ACL on a directory to impose more complex permissions. Both of these will be automatically inheritable by any sub-directories created by a regular user, so you just need to set up the top directory as appropriate using root privileges, and then regular user(s) can do the rest.

> ... bad superblock on /dev/xvdi, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

Since you said manual mounting is successful, these must not be the problem.